# section with ng-include hide and show

Tags: angularjs, show-hide, angularjs-ng-include

I have an ng-include directive inside a section which needs to conditionally hide the data being shown from ng-include url. If i hide section, I never get the ng-include data but if i start with visible section every thing works. here is some ex :

if condition: true;

```
<section ng-show="condition">
<div ng-include='url'>
</section>
```

Everything works as expected.

however if i first start with condition: false; i never see data from ng-include even when i set condition to true (via event)

What's wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use `ng-if` instead. As per my understanding the DOM is not reproduced on show hide, but when we use `ng-if`, DOM changes in the sense that element gets removed from DOM and injected back based on condition is false or true.